# Qt for iOS: code signing is required

Tags: c++, ios, qt4

I have yes smite  version installed on my MaC and also Xcode version is 6.1. I downloaded Qt from official website and tried to build a very simple program. However, it gave me 3 error messages

:-1: error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “(null)” were found.

:-1: error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.1'

:-1: error: Xcodebuild failed.

I searched on web on possible solutions but could not find any. what should I do build my applications on qt?

Answer (score 7):

Add this to your qmake file for the project:

```
setting.name = DEVELOPMENT_TEAM
setting.value = XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
QMAKE_MAC_XCODE_SETTINGS += setting
```

Replace the X's with the actual value for your team. Note, the value is not the team name - it's some other identifier. To get that value (after downloading provisioning profiles in XCode), do the following :

- Manually set the code signing team in an XCode project from within XCode (project general tab).
- View the project file's "package contents"
- Open the file project.pbxproj in a raw text editor.
- Search for DEVELOPMENT_TEAM.

Comment: your `setting.name = DEVELOPMENT_TEAM` technique works nicely. How to get the field `ProvisioningStyle` added into `project.pbxproj` using `Qmake` ?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but you might want to try your luck following the same pattern here? This qmake variable `setting` is named arbitrarily.  You could create one called `setting2` or `styleSetting` etc. the question is more about what viable options there are for XCode settings.  I feel like I posted that before...  I'll take a quick look...

Comment: I tried with `setting2.name = PROVISIONING_STYLE`. But that ended up the `ProvisioningStyle` field in wrong place. I have raised a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45091222/how-can-enforce-qmake-to-contain-provisioningstyle-developmentteam-field) exactly on this just now. Appreciate if you could lend in some suggestion on it

Answer (score 3):

Add this to the qmake file for your project:

```
ios: {
    QMAKE_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = ABCDEF0123
    QMAKE_PROVISIONING_PROFILE = 12345678-abcd-1234-abcd-12345678abcd
}
```

To get these settings read your provisioning profile in `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profile`, specifically, the following sections:

```xml
<dict>
    <!-- ... -->
    <key>TeamIdentifier</key>
    <array>
            <string>ABCDEF0123</string>
    </array>
    <!-- ... -->
    <key>UUID</key>
    <string>12345678-abcd-1234-abcd-12345678abcd</string>
    <!-- ... -->
</dict>
```

Reference:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html