# QMake: Specifying custom Info.plist file for iOS App

Tags: qt, qmake

I have an iOS application built using Qt(QML) for which I want to use a custom Info.plist file.

To do this, I built the project as usual (resulting in QMake providing a default Info.plist file). I then went to the Application bundle (inside the .app file) and copied the generated Info.plist file to my source tree. After copying, I modified this file to make the necessary customizations I needed (I just changed the screen orientation settings, nothing else).

I now specified the path to this customised Info.plist to file in the .pro for my application like so:

```
ios{
    QMAKE_INFO_PLIST = packages/ios/Info.plist
}
```

When I now hit build, I get the following compiler error:

```
Check dependencies
Code Sign error: Automatic provisioning profile selection unavailable: A bundle identifier is required for automatic provisioning profile selection. Either enter a bundle identifier in the Info.plist, or select a provisioning profile to use in the build settings.
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.2'
```

Has someone else run into this? I am using Qt 5.4.1. Am building on OSX.

Comment: *enter a bundle identifier in the Info.plist* https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-102070

Comment: @SimonWarta I did read up on bundle identifiers. There is already a bundle identifier in the Info.plist file that was generated by QMake. I have not touched that setting.

Comment: If you set `QMAKE_INFO_PLIST`, you explicitly overwrite qmake's default `Info.plist` with your own file, such that you need to take care of that by yourself. Can you add the content of your `packages/ios/Info.plist`?

Comment: @SimonWarta Thanks for taking a look:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_3UZN1ZieQgSk9vejBpaldjOGs

Comment: I don't think qmake is able to handle binary `Info.plist` files because it uses `sed` to find and replace some variables. Make sure you store it in XML format.

Comment: How can I store the Info.plist in XML format? I am just opening the plist files in the Plist editor that comes with Xcode. Is there a way I can get Xcode to save it as XML and not binary?

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to export Plist files as Plist XML instead of binary. Let me try building with it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your copy of `Info.plist` is in XML format, not binary.

This is necessary because `qmake` uses `sed` to replace [some variables](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-info-plist) during the build process. E.g.

```
 @sed -e "s,@SHORT_VERSION@,1.0,g" -e "s,@FULL_VERSION@,1.0.0,g" -e "s,@TYPEINFO@,????,g" -e "s,@BUNDLEIDENTIFIER@,com.example.product,g" -e "s,@ICON@,myproduct.icns,g" -e "s,@EXECUTABLE@,MyProduct,g" -e "s,@TYPEINFO@,????,g" ../../project/subproject/Info.plist >MyProject.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

I opened a [Qt bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-45357) because qmake should check that.

Answer (score 3):

Further to the accepted answer:

1. Ensure that QMAKE_INFO_PLIST **=** and *not* QMAKE_INFO_PLIST **+=**
   (I did this, argh).
2. If after opening the qmake-generated .xcodeproj file in Xcode you
   'Update to recommended settings' across the board, don't copy the Info.plist back to
   your source tree. This will wipe out the bundle identifier for
   next time.
3. If you need to add code-signing (so that you can actually build and run within Creator), the way to do so can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251042/qt-for-ios-code-signing-is-required).
4. In my experience, the custom Info.plist and code-signing qmake
   additions are best put in the project's .pro file, and not the
   auto-generated deployment.pri file. The latter works, but I got a
   compiler warning in Xcode about Info.plist not being in the working
   copy, and warnings anger the demons in my head.