# How can enforce `qmake` to contain `ProvisioningStyle` $ `DevelopmentTeam` fields in `project.pbxproj`?

Tags: qt, qmake, xcodebuild, ios-provisioning, pbxproj

I am using `Qmake` command line to build my app for `iOS` and I am struggling to sign my app with `xcodebuild` because the `MyApp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` that `qmake` is generating does not the contain the following fields at all

```
ProvisioningStyle
DevelopmentTeam
```

**How can enforce `qmake` to contain `ProvisioningStyle` $ `DevelopmentTeam` fields in `project.pbxproj`?**

I dont need to have any certain value to be set into the 2 fields. Only, need the fields to be present in appropriate places in `project.pbxproj`. Opening & `MyApp.xcodeproj` in `Xcode` UI IDE & just checking-unchecking the `Automatically manage signing` option under `Project>General settings` adds the fields into `project.pbxproj`. How can I get `qmake` to add them for me?

Answer (score 1):

As you know, I answered the DevelopmentTeam detail on this SO thread:
[Qt for iOS: code signing is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251042/qt-for-ios-code-signing-is-required/40381548?noredirect=1#comment77145725_40381548)

You commented that you tried the same pattern for `PROVISISIONING_STYLE` but did you try `ProvisioningStyle`?  I'm just a bit unclear what you did and what the results were.

Comment: Yes. I tried `ProvisioningStyle`. But, the issue is that it ends up in `buildSettings = {` section of `project.pbxproj` . Whereas it should be in `attributes = {` section of `project.pbxproj`. Only when it is in `attributes = {` section, `Xcode` picks it up correctly.

Comment: Please check a `project.pbxproj` generated out of `Xcode` to understand my comment correctly. The format defined by `Xcode` for `project.pbxproj` does not seem to be adhered in this case by `qmake`. is there some way I can enforce from `qmake` level to automatically choose a `provisioning profile` ? I am using Xcode 8

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not working on my Mac, and I'm neck deep in other issues.  What we want to know is how QMAKE_MAC_XCODE_SETTINGS gets applied.  That should point us in the right direction.  Can you post your compile output from Qt?  We'll see where that gets mixed into the build process. (I.e. let's search for the DEVELOPMENT_TEAM variable/value etc. in that)

Comment: I'm expecting to see some XCode command line tool that gets brought into play.

Comment: Worse case scenario, you can write a script to edit that file post linkage via qmake.  I've done a variety of tricky tasks that way for which Qt couldn't possibly have a built-in solution for.

Comment: Ok. Let me try some a sed command technique to insert the text I want to in the pbxproj.

Comment: I saw some posts where other developers did that.  I can help you get that firing off in your qmake at the right time if you want.

Comment: I'd still suggest figuring out what the qmake xcode variable does though.  I'm guessing Qt used a cleaner solution (hopefully!)