# How do I set ios app bundle Id from QT application

Tags: ios, qt, qml

I have developed an application by using Qt/QML.
Successfully run the application on an iOS device.

How do I set the iOS app bundle ID from the Qt application since it resets each time I build?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using QT 5.11.1 or higher, set the following variable in your .pro file:

```
TARGET = app    

QMAKE_TARGET_BUNDLE_PREFIX = com.xxxx
```

The final result is a bundle identifier of com.xxxx.app.  If you're using an older QT, you might get hit with the following bug:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-66462

For my signing to work I had to combine this answer with the answer from this post:

[Qt for iOS: code signing is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251042/qt-for-ios-code-signing-is-required)

To save you the time, here is my complete .pro

```
ios: {
  QMAKE_TARGET_BUNDLE_PREFIX = com.xxxx
  QMAKE_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = XXXX
  QMAKE_PROVISIONING_PROFILE = XXXXX
}
```

Please keep in mind you need to have your provisioning profile setup for the connected device in question before any of this will work.  To do that you'll need to goto the apple.developer website.  There is lots of documentation on manual provisional certs.  I had to go through the manual process, and then go into xcode -> account -> Download Manual Profiles; before mine worked.